# Electron Webpack Typescript SerialPort

Tags: typescript, webpack, serial-port, electron

hi i can't get SerialPort to work in electron.
And im not shure if it is an webpack typescript oder electrin error.
i tried some different settings in webpack but never got it to work ant always with te same error.

my webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

const commonConfig = {
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: '[name].js'
    },
    node: {
        __dirname: false,
    },
    watchOptions: {
        poll: 100
    },
    mode: 'development',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts?$/,
                loader: 'ts-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.ts', '.json']
    },
    plugins: [new CopyWebpackPlugin([
        { from: './src/*.html', to: './[name].html' },
        { from: './src/*.css', to: './[name].css' },
    ], {
        flatten: true
    })]
};

module.exports = [
    Object.assign(
        {
            target: 'electron-main',
            entry: {main: './src/main.ts'}
        },
        commonConfig),
    Object.assign(
        {
            target: 'electron-renderer',
            entry: {gui: './src/gui.ts'},
            plugins: [new HtmlWebpackPlugin()]
        },
        commonConfig)
];
```

my gui.ts

```
import * as SerialPort from "serialport";

SerialPort.list().then(ports => {
    console.log(ports);
});
```

and the error in electron is

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at eval (external_"stream":1)
    at Object.stream (gui.js:471)
    at __webpack_require__ (gui.js:20)
    at eval (stream.js:1)
    at Object../node_modules/@serialport/stream/stream.js (gui.js:349)
    at __webpack_require__ (gui.js:20)
    at eval (index.js:1)
    at Object../node_modules/serialport/lib/index.js (gui.js:393)
    at __webpack_require__ (gui.js:20)
    at eval (gui.ts:2)
```

Comment: Your first line in webpack.config.js doesn't look like valid Javascript. Is that just a typo?

Comment: No its an inserting Error i fixed it sry for that.

Comment: @ChristianWilling Did you figure it out?